# Implicit conversion and calling a function

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

What is the use of implicit conversion in C++ when I call a function that takes parameters as int, while I pass an argument that is double? Why is this not a compile time error? What goes on in the run-time stack that allows this to happen?

```
#include <iostream>
void foo(int num);

int main() {
    double doub= 4.9;
    foo(doub);
    return 0;
}

void foo(int num){
    std::cout<<num<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: *Why is this not a compile time error?* Back in the 80's programming languages weren't as type-safe as they are now. C++ is backwards compatible with C.

Comment: Runtime stack, nothing. You don't want this at runtime. You'd slow down everything just to catch a few bad lines of code. Crank up your compiler's warning level and you should get a conversion warning.

Comment: @user4581301 does it not mess with the compiler since int and double are of the same size? Is doing implicit conversion like this even helpful at times?

Comment: @HamzaKhan: no they are not the same size double is 8 bytes where int is 4 only

Comment: @Raindrop7 sorry I worded it wrong, I meant does it not confuse the compiler since int and double are of different sizes. How does the compiler handle this?

Comment: here is an article on implicit conversion: [link text](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a long list of all of the [implicit conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) that C++ does.  This particular one is covered under:

> **Floating–integral conversions** A prvalue of floating-point type can be converted to a prvalue of any integer type. The fractional part is
>   truncated, that is, the fractional part is discarded. If the value
>   cannot fit into the destination type, the behavior is undefined (even
>   when the destination type is unsigned, modulo arithmetic does not
>   apply). If the destination type is bool, this is a boolean conversion
>   (see below).

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I would like to know. What is the use of allowing implicit conversion? In my opinion it just makes things more tricky for the compiler. Why not just remove it now?

Comment: @HamzaKhan40-some years of code would break. Changes like that are handled very carefully. If you want this to be an error, turn on the warnings  appropriate for your compiler and set the warnings are errors flag.

Comment: @HamzaKhan From a practical perspective, people expect numbers to be numbers.  They expect converting a floating-point number to an integer to grab the integer component of the number, and they expect converting an integer to a floating-point number to create the closest floating-point representation of that integer.